# Con BOOTSTRAP 5 ¿Como hacer para que la barra lateral no haga scroll?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Muy buen día, tengo un problema con una barra lateral que hice con bootstrap  al momento de hacer scroll en la página la barra lateral también lo hace

Así se ve:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**y esto es lo que hace cuando hago scroll abajo para ver las demás tablas:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya he buscado e intentado varias soluciones como poner la clase **position-fixed** o incluso como estilo de css
pero lo que hace es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En efecto la barra lateral ya no hace scroll junto con el contenido del **Panel** pero el contenido de este ignora la barra lateral.

les dejo mi código para que vean bien como está compuesto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">
        <!-- La barra lateral empieza aquí -->
        <div class="bg-white" id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <div class="sidebar-heading text-center py-4 primary-text fs-4 fw-bold text-uppercase border-bottom">
                <img src="" style="width: 50px; height: auto; margin: 5px;"> COORP
            </div>
            <div class="list-group list-group-flush my-3">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text active">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined me-2">speed</span>Panel
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text fw-bold">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined me-2">app_registration</span>Registrar Ticket
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text fw-bold">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined me-2">manage_search</span>Consultar Ticket
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text fw-bold">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined me-2">analytics</span>Estatus de Reportes
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text fw-bold">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined me-2">dataset</span>Gestión de Reportes
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text fw-bold">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined me-2">forum</span>FORO
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent text-danger fw-bold">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined me-2">logout</span>Cerrar sesión
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- La barra lateral termina aquí -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent py-4 px-4">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined" id="menu-toggle">format_align_left</span>
                    <h2 class="fs-2 m-0">Panel</h2>
                </div>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle second-text fw-bold" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <img src="img/avatar.png" style="width: 80px; height: auto; margin: 5px;"> ADMIN
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Perfil</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Ajustes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Cerrar sesión</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="container fluid px-4">
                <!-- Contenido del TABLERO inicia AQUÍ -->
                <div class="row g-3 my-2">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="p-3 bg-primary shadow-sm d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center rounded">
                            <div>
                                <h3 class="fs-2">007</h3>
                                <p class="fs-5">Ticket(s)</p>
                            </div>
                            <span class="material-symbols-outlined fs-1 primary-text border rounded-full secondary-bg p-3">local_activity</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="p-3 bg-warning shadow-sm d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center rounded-3">
                            <div>
                                <h3 class="fs-2">002</h3>
                                <p class="fs-5">Por atender</p>
                            </div>
                            <span class="material-symbols-outlined fs-1 primary-text border rounded-full secondary-bg p-3">pending_actions</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="p-3 bg-danger shadow-sm d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center rounded-3">
                            <div>
                                <h3 class="fs-2">004</h3>
                                <p class="fs-5">Atendiendose</p>
                            </div>
                            <span class="material-symbols-outlined fs-1 primary-text border rounded-full secondary-bg p-3">assignment_ind</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="p-3 bg-info shadow-sm d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center rounded-3">
                            <div>
                                <h3 class="fs-2">001</h3>
                                <p class="fs-5">Terminado(s)</p>
                            </div>
                            <span class="material-symbols-outlined fs-1 primary-text border rounded-full secondary-bg p-3">verified</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="row my-5">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <span class="material-symbols-outlined fs-4 primary-text border rounded-full secondary-bg p-3 m-2">tab_recent</span>
                        <h3 class="fs-4 mb3">Actividad Reciente</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <table class="table bg-white rounded shadow-sm table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                                    <th scope="col">1</th>
                                    <th scope="col">2</th>
                                    <th scope="col">3</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row"><span class="material-symbols-outlined up">arrow_upward</span>1<span class="material-symbols-outlined down">arrow_downward</span></th>
                                    <td>area</td>
                                    <td>asignado</td>
                                    <td>estatus</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row"><span class="material-symbols-outlined up">arrow_upward</span>2<span class="material-symbols-outlined down">arrow_downward</span></th>
                                    <td>area</td>
                                    <td>asignado</td>
                                    <td>estatus</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row"><span class="material-symbols-outlined up">arrow_upward</span>3<span class="material-symbols-outlined down">arrow_downward</span></th>
                                    <td>area</td>
                                    <td>asignado</td>
                                    <td>estatus</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row"><span class="material-symbols-outlined up">arrow_upward</span>4<span class="material-symbols-outlined down">arrow_downward</span></th>
                                    <td>area</td>
                                    <td>asignado</td>
                                    <td>estatus</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Contenido del TABLERO termina AQUÍ -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-oP6HI9z1XaZNBrJURtCoUT5SUnxFr8s3BzRl+cbzUq8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

css:

```
:root{
    --main-bg-color: #004036;
    --main-text-color: #333;
    --second-text-color: #bbbec5;
    --second-bg-color: #effcf9;
  }
  
  .primary-text{
    color: var(--main-text-color);
  }
  
  .second-text{
    color: var(--second-text-color);
  }
  
  .primary-bg{
    background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
  }
  
  .secondary-bg{
    background-color: var(--second-bg-color);
  }
  
  .rounded-full{
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
  
  #wrapper{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background: rgb(120,176,97);
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(120,176,97,1) 0%, rgba(70,138,88,1) 33%, rgba(29,101,74,1) 66%);
  }
  
  #sidebar-wrapper{
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin-left: -15rem;
    transition: margin 0.4s ease-out;
  }
  
  #sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-heading{
    padding: 0.875rem;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
  
  #sidebar-wrapper .list-group{
    width: 15rem;
  }
  
  #page-content-wrapper{
    min-width: 100vw;
  }
  
  #wrapped.toggled #sidebar-wrapper{
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  
  #menu-toggle{
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .up, .down{
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .list-group-item{
    border: none;
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  
  .list-group-item.active{
    background-color: transparent;
    color: var(--main-text-color);
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar-wrapper{
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    #page-content-wrapper{
      min-width: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper{
      margin-left: -15rem;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El camino que tu estas siguiendo de dejas la barra lateral como `fixed` es totalmente posible, pero requiere retocar mucho CSS. Con position `sticky` podría funcionar también, pero el flex que tienes molesta para la implementación.

Pero existe otro camino más simple, dado que tu página no tiene cabecera

Tú tienes la siguiente estructura:

- #wrapper -> El todo

  - #sidebar-wrapper -> barra lateral
  - #page-content-wrapper -> contenido principal

Tienes que dejar que `#wrapper` cubra el 100% del alto siempre fijo, para que `#page-content-wrapper` tenga scroll cuando desborda, de esta manera el contenido tiene su propio scroll sin afectar la barra lateral y como no tienes una cabecera el efecto es el mismo.

Esto:

```
#wrapper{
   height:100vh;
}
#page-content-wrapper{
   overflow:auto;
}
```

Ejemplo funcional :

```css
:root{
    --main-bg-color: #004036;
    --main-text-color: #333;
    --second-text-color: #bbbec5;
    --second-bg-color: #effcf9;
  }
  
  .primary-text{
    color: var(--main-text-color);
  }
  
  .second-text{
    color: var(--second-text-color);
  }
  
  .primary-bg{
    background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
  }
  
  .secondary-bg{
    background-color: var(--second-bg-color);
  }
  
  .rounded-full{
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
  
  #wrapper{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background: rgb(120,176,97);
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(120,176,97,1) 0%, rgba(70,138,88,1) 33%, rgba(29,101,74,1) 66%);
  }
  
  #sidebar-wrapper{
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin-left: -15rem;
    transition: margin 0.4s ease-out;
  }
  
  #sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-heading{
    padding: 0.875rem;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
  
  #sidebar-wrapper .list-group{
    width: 15rem;
  }
  
  #page-content-wrapper{
    min-width: 100vw;
  }
  
  #wrapped.toggled #sidebar-wrapper{
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  
  #menu-toggle{
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .up, .down{
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .list-group-item{
    border: none;
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  
  .list-group-item.active{
    background-color: transparent;
    color: var(--main-text-color);
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar-wrapper{
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    #page-content-wrapper{
      min-width: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper{
      margin-left: -15rem;
    }
  }
#wrapper{
  height:100vh;
}
  #page-content-wrapper{
     overflow:auto;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">
        <!-- La barra lateral empieza aquí -->
        <div class="bg-white" id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <div class="sidebar-heading text-center py-4 primary-text fs-4 fw-bold text-uppercase border-bottom">
                <img src="" style="width: 50px; height: auto; margin: 5px;"> COORP
            </div>
            <div class="list-group list-group-flush my-3">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text active">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined me-2">speed</span>Panel
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text fw-bold">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined me-2">app_registration</span>Registrar Ticket
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text fw-bold">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined me-2">manage_search</span>Consultar Ticket
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text fw-bold">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined me-2">analytics</span>Estatus de Reportes
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text fw-bold">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined me-2">dataset</span>Gestión de Reportes
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text fw-bold">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined me-2">forum</span>FORO
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent text-danger fw-bold">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined me-2">logout</span>Cerrar sesión
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- La barra lateral termina aquí -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent py-4 px-4">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined" id="menu-toggle">format_align_left</span>
                    <h2 class="fs-2 m-0">Panel</h2>
                </div>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle second-text fw-bold" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <img src="img/avatar.png" style="width: 80px; height: auto; margin: 5px;"> ADMIN
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Perfil</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Ajustes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Cerrar sesión</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="container fluid px-4">
                <!-- Contenido del TABLERO inicia AQUÍ -->
                <div class="row g-3 my-2">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="p-3 bg-primary shadow-sm d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center rounded">
                            <div>
                                <h3 class="fs-2">007</h3>
                                <p class="fs-5">Ticket(s)</p>
                            </div>
                            <span class="material-symbols-outlined fs-1 primary-text border rounded-full secondary-bg p-3">local_activity</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="p-3 bg-warning shadow-sm d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center rounded-3">
                            <div>
                                <h3 class="fs-2">002</h3>
                                <p class="fs-5">Por atender</p>
                            </div>
                            <span class="material-symbols-outlined fs-1 primary-text border rounded-full secondary-bg p-3">pending_actions</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="p-3 bg-danger shadow-sm d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center rounded-3">
                            <div>
                                <h3 class="fs-2">004</h3>
                                <p class="fs-5">Atendiendose</p>
                            </div>
                            <span class="material-symbols-outlined fs-1 primary-text border rounded-full secondary-bg p-3">assignment_ind</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="p-3 bg-info shadow-sm d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center rounded-3">
                            <div>
                                <h3 class="fs-2">001</h3>
                                <p class="fs-5">Terminado(s)</p>
                            </div>
                            <span class="material-symbols-outlined fs-1 primary-text border rounded-full secondary-bg p-3">verified</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="row my-5">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <span class="material-symbols-outlined fs-4 primary-text border rounded-full secondary-bg p-3 m-2">tab_recent</span>
                        <h3 class="fs-4 mb3">Actividad Reciente</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <table class="table bg-white rounded shadow-sm table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                                    <th scope="col">1</th>
                                    <th scope="col">2</th>
                                    <th scope="col">3</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row"><span class="material-symbols-outlined up">arrow_upward</span>1<span class="material-symbols-outlined down">arrow_downward</span></th>
                                    <td>area</td>
                                    <td>asignado</td>
                                    <td>estatus</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row"><span class="material-symbols-outlined up">arrow_upward</span>2<span class="material-symbols-outlined down">arrow_downward</span></th>
                                    <td>area</td>
                                    <td>asignado</td>
                                    <td>estatus</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row"><span class="material-symbols-outlined up">arrow_upward</span>3<span class="material-symbols-outlined down">arrow_downward</span></th>
                                    <td>area</td>
                                    <td>asignado</td>
                                    <td>estatus</td>
                                </tr>
                             
                                <script>
                                    for(let i=0;i<20; i++){
                                      document.write(`<tr> <th scope="row"><span class="material-symbols-outlined up">arrow_upward</span>4<span class="material-symbols-outlined down">arrow_downward</span></th>
                                    <td>area</td>
                                    <td>asignado</td>
                                    <td>estatus</td>
                                </tr>`);
                                    }
                                </script>
                                   
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Contenido del TABLERO termina AQUÍ -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-oP6HI9z1XaZNBrJURtCoUT5SUnxFr8s3BzRl+cbzUq8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```